# App request dialog shows 500 internal server error

Tags: facebook-graph-api, dialog

I'm using facebook's app app request dialog. It used to work fine...but I get the following error message with infinite loading image.

```
"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - https://www.facebook.com/dialog/apprequest?access_token=AAACvZBzj3fc0BAETVk8NOCiXqsGq2uXlUC0EUUX1pMXIPWxfIrhbboHQCvBPR0XKasdfFU30ZCpq1C4GqfEZD&api_key=19349352asdf95789&app_id=19349adf27395789&channel=https%3A%2F%2Fs-static.ak.fbcdn.net%2Fconnect%2Fxd_proxy.php%3Fversion%3D3%23cb%3Df3fb42d06cf1cf4%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fasdf%252Ff3aaa156051f95%26relation%3Dparent.parent%26transport%3Dpostmessage&channel_url=https%3A%2F%2Fs-static.ak.fbcdn.net%2Fconnect%2Fxd_proxy.php%3Fversion%3D3%23cb%3Df3b386a6f30f464%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fasdfm%252Ff3aaa156051f95%26relation%3Dparent.parent%26transport%3Dpostmessage&data=%7B%7D&display=iframe&locale=en_US&message=0&next=https%3A%2F%2Fs-static.ak.fbcdn.net%2Fconnect%2Fxd_proxy.php%3Fversion%3D3%23cb%3Df60d0ad8457e2%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fdev-sherlock.thecimarrongroup.com%252Ff3aaa156051f95%26relation%3Dparent%26transport%3Dpostmessage%26frame%3Df19043b1779432%26result%3D%2522xxRESULTTOKENxx%2522&sdk=joey"

uncaught exception: Error: Permission denied for <http://static.ak.facebook.com> to get property Proxy.InstallTrigger
```

Is it an error on facebook end?

Comment: ha...never mind...it was my mistake. I put FB.ui('apprequest') instead of apprequests